# Remove text from confirmation message

Tags: plugin-development

How can I remove `View post` words from Post published confirmation message ?

[image]

Comment: What's the reason you want to remove that link?

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. It is unnecessary to me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the link, or do you actually just want this post type to not have public URLs?

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. I wouldn't like to show `View post` text. I would like to keep the space blank/white. Thanks.

Comment: Why though? This is the second question you’ve asked about hiding the link. Why are you trying to hide it? If the post is supposed to be private or hidden then that’s a different problem than trying to just visually hide the links.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. This is unnecessary to me. Thanks.

Comment: Without further context the simple answer would be "use CSS to target the link and apply a `display: none;` declaration." To enqueue a stylesheet for the dashboard use a `wp_enqueue_style()` call in the the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. The actual targeting and hiding of the link itself is a generic CSS problem, and as such may be considered off-topic for our stack.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would keep that link (despite the page has other links/ways for accessing the post).

But if you must, you can remove that "View post" link, or change the entire message, using the [`post_updated_messages` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated_messages/). E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_post_updated_messages' );
function my_post_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    // Note the array index, which is 6 for the "post published" message.
    $messages['post'][6] = 'Post published.';

    return $messages;
}
```

The above is for the `post` post type, but is also used as the default for other post types, if `$messages['<post type>'][<message number>]` is not set. So if you want to target a specific post type other than `post`, then you can copy the `$messages['post']` or `$messages['page']`, and change only the messages that you wish to change. Example for a post type named `news`:

```php
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'my_news_updated_messages' );
function my_news_updated_messages( $messages ) {
    $messages['news'] = $messages['post']; // copy the entire messages for 'post'

    $messages['news'][6] = 'Post published.';

    return $messages;
}
```

And for WordPress v6.0.1, you can see the default messages [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4c265b66297074f09d66c17d9f14d11a5fffdb00/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L180-L210).

Comment: Thanks @Sally CJ. It is working when I first Publish post. But I am getting same Previous message when I Update post. How can I get same result like Publish post when I update a post ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4c265b66297074f09d66c17d9f14d11a5fffdb00/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L180-L210) linked to from my answer? There are several messages there that have a link to view the published/updated post, so you just need to check the message's number or array index, and then just customize that specific message. E.g. For the "post updated" message, the number is 1, so you could do `$messages['post'][1] = 'Post updated.';` and the link would be gone.